# Android SDK seems to limit download speeds when using URLConnection

Tags: android, performance, http

I'm trying to implement a very simple download logic for Android. But it seems to be very slow, even though my internet is much faster. I've tried the same code on multiple devices on the same WLAN and I get different results, but always much slower than should be possible.
When I output the bytesRead in the loop to the console it's never using all of the available buffer, but seems to have a very strict limit on how much it can use.
I've tried with and without the BufferedInputStream, but that made no difference.

```
        InputStream httpInputStream = null;
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        try {
            int bufferSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10;
            URL url = new URL(item.getSource().toString());
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            httpInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream(), bufferSize);
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(item.getLocal());

            byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            long totalBytesRead = 0;
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = httpInputStream.read(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.length)) != -1) {
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                if( this.state == STATE_CANCELLED ) {
                    this.closeStreams(httpInputStream, fileOutputStream);
                    return false;
                }
                fileOutputStream.write(dataBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            this.closeStreams(httpInputStream, fileOutputStream);
        }
```

Strange thing is, I have 500mbit available on my network. My Windows PC usually get's close to that. My iPhone reaches 220mbit and more. My Samsung Galaxy A40 reaches just 30mbit and my Redmi Note 8 Pro reaches around 130mbit. So it seems the different phones allow for different speeds. But even so my download routine is constantly much slower than all of those values.

Any hints on what is going on or what I can improve would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your buffer is much too big. 20KB would do.

Comment: You are assigning a BufferedInputStream to an InputStream.

Comment: I never saw a check for STATE_CANCELLED.

Comment: Buffersize: It doesn't make a difference, I've tried all kinds of sizes.

Comment: BufferedInputStream: What's your point? A BufferedInputStream IS an InputStream. It extends it. InputStream is just the base version of ALL InputStreams. This doesn't change the BufferedInputStream. But that's basic OOP and has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: STATE_CANCELLED: This originates from that code being executed in a Runnable, which can be cancelled.